# Efficient way of extracting from an array of objects

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array, numpy

I have a an array of objects in python:

```
meshnodearray = ['MeshNode object', 'MeshNode object', 'MeshNode object', ...]
```

Where for example first 'MeshNode object' is:

```
({'coordinates': (15.08, 273.01, 322.61), 'instanceName': None, 'label': 1})
```

I need to create an array of coordinates like this:

```
NODEcoo = np.zeros((nnod,3),dtype='float64')
for i in meshnodearray:
    NODEcoo[i.label-1,0:] = np.array(i.coordinates)
```

For large arrays this is slow. Is there a more efficient way of doing this, maybe without the for loop?

Comment: If you have to do that for all objects in the array then I see no other way.

Comment: Yes I need to do this for all the objects.

Comment: list comprehensions will do then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try extracting the coordinates into a python list of coordinates and converting it into a numpy array in one go. If the label values are sequential from 1 to `nnod`, it's as simple as this:

```
coords = [ n['coordinates'] for n in meshnodearray ]
NODEcoo = np.array(coords)
```

It would be somewhat better to do this with a generator (which would let you avoid creating the intermediate array), but numpy can create only one-dimensional arrays from a generator, with `numpy.fromiter()`.

Comment: Thanks, this is a little faster. Could this be done maybe in parallel to further speed it up?